# What units of power/energy consumption have Energy Levels in the Energy Instrument for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments, energy

I'm actually measuring the energy consumption of my iOS application through the Energy instrument. I want to know the measure (e.g., in Joules) of the energy levels given by the Energy Instrument for an iOS app. Is there any relationship between the common energy consumption unit (Joules) and those energy levels? Thanks in advance for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Energy Diagnostics reports power consumption as an un-united number between 0 and 20; we call them "electricities" at my office.  [Powergremlin](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/11/14/introducing-powergremlin/) gives you some insight into the actual numbers that make up said "electicity" units.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which app is set up on the platform, also the specified standard to the calculations such as British/American/SI standards. In general, in the European measurement system, the energy unit can be expressed in GWh/MWh/kWh and in the British system is "BTU" or "ktoe". Also, there are online platforms to convert these units to each other